# Get application name from EJB on Weblogic 11g

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jndi, weblogic11g, mbeans

Is there a way to find out the deployment name of an application from a server managed object that itself is in, on Weblogic 11g? For example, can I get the application name a stateless bean in deployed with, from that stateless bean itself?

I found some servers allow for JNDI lookup of `java:app/AppName`, but it doesn't seem to work on Weblogic. Also, I know I can get the names of all the deployed applications (and much more) using MBean, but I don't know how to identify 'the one' that I'm interested in without previously passing the application name to my bean, which defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the Java EE 8 specification, ch. EE.5.15 "Application Name and Module Name References"

> A component may access the name of the current application using the pre-defined JNDI name `java:app/AppName`. A component may access the name of the current module using the pre-defined JNDI name `java:module/ModuleName`. Both of these names are represented by `String` objects.

And later, at EE.5.15.2 "Java EE Product Provider’s Responsibilities":

> The Java EE Product Provider is responsible for providing the correct application name and module name String objects as required by this specification.

So Java EE compliant products are *required* to provide the JNDI value you mention.

For me (currently on WildFly 15) this works:

```
@Resource(name = "java:app/AppName")
private String appName;

@Resource(name = "java:module/ModuleName")
private String moduleName;
```

Comment: We are running WebLogic Server 10.3.4.0 with Java 1.6.0_37. I'm not sure whether this is the cause (most likely is), but your examples, when put in a stateless EJB bean, yield null values. Other resources get injected as expected.

Comment: Yes, you are probably running on a server that supports an older version of J(2)EE that does not specify these JNDI values (I do no think the Java version plays a role). Can you tweak the deployment descriptors of your modules? I believe you can still add JNDI entries of type `String` from the deployment descriptors - but under the `java:comp/env` namespace.

Comment: Currently, I use this approach, in a somewhat different arrangement. I use an ant script to deploy to WL and pass in the application name as a normal string resource using the deployment plan. This is, however, cumbersome, and I would like to avoid it if possible. The whole motivation of trying to get the application name dynamically is to avoid doing it "manually".